# calling a method in model from view

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-3, model-view-controller, methods, model

I am trying to evaluate which indicator needs to be displayed next to an item based on if it's been viewed before or not, new comments etc. Until I decide on a symbol to use, I just want a number to display.

in my Report Model i have

```
def self.indicator
    #bunch of if elsif statements returning a number 0-3
end
```

in my view i have

```
<% @reports.each do |report| %>
    <%= report.indicator %>
<% end %>
```

I get `undefined method 'indicator'`

I thought I had a grip on how methods work... but clearly not, what am I doing wrong?

Comment: Please show the full error message.  Does it include a class/object or is that undefined method on nil?

Comment: Also please show the controller statement for the view that does the @reports = Report.all or Report.find(...), etc.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Try

```
def indicator
    #bunch of if elsif statements returning a number 0-3
end
```

You don't need the self as it [corrected to] is a class level method.

Comment: Could you tell is it all right to call a model method in the view, because we are skipping the controller in that way? Also, if it is a not good practice, what is the alternative?

Answer (score 6):

In your view, you are calling an instance method `indicator` on each report object

```
report.indicator
```

But in your model, you have defined a class method. So, to make it work, define your indicator method as an instance method, too:

```
def indicator
  #bunch of if elsif statements returning a number 0-3
end
```

Answer (score 2):

Your iteration variable `report` is used for going through every instance of `@reports`. With `self.indicator` you are declaring a class method (via `self.name`). So this would make it possible to call `Report.indicator`. What you want is to call just on a single instance of Report, so you can define the method indicator in your model like this:

```
def indicator
  #bunch of if elsif statements returning a number 0-3
end
```

Now this should work!